# Create tree structure from javascript array of object

Tags: javascript, json

I have an array of objects like this..

```
var obj_1 = {id:1, title:"Title 1", unitId:0, line: 0};
var obj_2 = {id:2, title:"Title 1.1", unitId:1, line: 0};
var obj_3 = {id:3, title:"Title 1.2", unitId:1, line: 1};
var obj_4 = {id:4, title:"Title 1.1.1", unitId:0, line: 1};
var obj_5 = {id:5, title:"Title 2", unitId:0, line: 1};

var obj_list = [obj_1,obj_2,obj_3,obj_4,obj_5];
```

I want to convert the json to tree structure, my result structure like this

```
Unit 0: {
  Line 0: {
     children: {
        {id:1, title:"Title 1", unitId:0, line: 0}
     }
  },
  Line 1: {
     children: {
        {id:4, title:"Title 1.1.1", unitId:0, line: 1},
        {id:5, title:"Title 2", unitId:0, line: 1}
     }
  }
}
Unit 1: {
  Line 0: {
     children: {
        {id:2, title:"Title 1.1", unitId:1, line: 0}
     }
  },
  Line 1: {
     children: {
        {id:2, title:"Title 1.2", unitId:1, line: 2}
     }
  }
}
```

If anyone know how to do, please answer. Thanks in advance

Comment: What did you try to accomplish the above task?

Comment: I have tried using foreach and array reduce but its didn't work.

Comment: Reduce is the right method to use

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could take an array of the wanted keys for nesting and build new object with this keys and push at the end the object to the `children` property.

```js
var data = [{ id: 1, title: "Title 1", unitId: 0, line: 0 }, { id: 2, title: "Title 1.1", unitId: 1, line: 0 }, { id: 3, title: "Title 1.2", unitId: 1, line: 1 }, { id: 4, title: "Title 1.1.1", unitId: 0, line: 1 }, { id: 5, title: "Title 2", unitId: 0, line: 1 }],
    keys = [['unitId', 'Unit'], ['line', 'Line']],
    result = data.reduce((r, o) => {
        var target = keys.reduce((q, [k, t]) => {
                var key = [t, o[k]].join(' ');
                return q[key] = q[key] || {};
            }, r);
        (target.children = target.children || []).push(o);
        return r;
    }, {});

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

The same with letters for a special key.

```js
var data = [{ id: 1, title: "Title 1", unitId: 0, line: 0 }, { id: 2, title: "Title 1.1", unitId: 1, line: 0 }, { id: 3, title: "Title 1.2", unitId: 1, line: 1 }, { id: 4, title: "Title 1.1.1", unitId: 0, line: 1 }, { id: 5, title: "Title 2", unitId: 0, line: 1 }],
    keys = [['unitId', 'Unit'], ['line', 'Line', v => (10 + v).toString(36).toUpperCase()]],
    result = data.reduce((r, o) => {
        var target = keys.reduce((q, [k, t, fn = v => v]) => {
                var key = [t, fn(o[k])].join(' ');
                return q[key] = q[key] || {};
            }, r);
        (target.children = target.children || []).push(o);
        return r;
    }, {});

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: If I want Line 0 to Line A and Line 1 to Line B...then what will I do ?

Comment: only for lines?

Comment: Now I want to push Line o and Line 1 into Unit 0.children..please reply me

Comment: please ask a new question.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58391221/javascript-array-of-object-to-tree-structure

Answer (score 0):

First: get the structure you desire:

```
const structure = [];
for (obj of obj_list) {
  if (!structure[obj.unitId]) {
    structure[obj.unitId] = [];
  }
  if (!structure[obj.unitId][obj.line]) {
    structure[obj.unitId][obj.line] = [];
  }
  structure[obj.unitId][obj.line].push(obj);
}
```

Next: output this in the format you desire.
You can probably handle this last step.

Answer (score 0):

There's probably a cleaner way, just wanted to give a quick answer

```
const obj_1 = { id: 1, title: 'Title 1', unitId: 0, line: 0 };
const obj_2 = { id: 2, title: 'Title 1.1', unitId: 1, line: 0 };
const obj_3 = { id: 3, title: 'Title 1.2', unitId: 1, line: 1 };
const obj_4 = { id: 4, title: 'Title 1.1.1', unitId: 0, line: 1 };
const obj_5 = { id: 5, title: 'Title 2', unitId: 0, line: 1 };

const obj_list = [obj_1, obj_2, obj_3, obj_4, obj_5];

newJson = {};
obj_list.forEach(el => {
    newJson[`unit${el.unitId}`] ? null : (newJson[`unit${el.unitId}`] = {});
    newJson[`unit${el.unitId}`][`line${el.line}`]
        ? null
        : (newJson[`unit${el.unitId}`][`line${el.line}`] = {});
    newJson[`unit${el.unitId}`][`line${el.line}`].children
        ? null
        : (newJson[`unit${el.unitId}`][`line${el.line}`].children = []);

    newJson[`unit${el.unitId}`][`line${el.line}`].children.push(el);
});

console.log(newJson);
```